# How do I change the ' in a string to %27 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, replace

I have this code:

```
var data = "I'm trying to send this with AJAX properly.";
data = encodeURIComponent(data);
data.replace("'", "%27");
data.replace(/'/, "%27");
alert(data); //Still not changed here...
```

I want to send that with AJAX to the database. But the ' is causing it to not send at all.
encodeURIComponent doesn't change the ' to its code %27, neither does data.replace.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not re-assigning `data`.

```
data = data.replace("'", "%27");
```

`replace()` returns the modified string, it doesn't modify the calling object string directly.

Comment: Note that this method will only replace the first occurence

Comment: To replace ALL occurences use a regex with the often forgotten "global" modifier: data = data.replace(/'/g, '%27').

Answer (score 5):

Use the escape method, it will URL-encode a string. **Note that the string.replace method only replaces the first occurence of a string when using a string as the match.** To replace all instances, you have to use a regex.

```
var foo = escape("'");
```

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel. Let's also rule out having to account for all characters that need to be encoded in a URI.

Comment: +1 and agree with John. Using `replace()` is a short-sighted solution. Admittedly my answer was focused on resolving the users specific code problem.

Comment: to replace all the occurrences, one can use foo.replace(new RegExp('\'', 'g'), escape("'"))

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.replace` returns the modified string, it does not modify the original. You must assign the returned value:

```
var newString = data.replace( "'", '%27' );
```